# Create Windows accounts and set file permissions from ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-permissions

I’m building an ASP.NET application, which will create Windows accounts and groups on the server, and set file/folder permissions for those accounts.

How do I accomplish that?

I’ve considered shelling out to CACLS.exe, but I got a feeling that’s going to get me into other problems eventually. Are there any other options in the .NET framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) I'm looking for. I'm going to wrap that up nicely in a WCF service (thanks, [Shiv Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501146/shiv-kumar)) and call that from my app.

Answer (score 2):

One way in which I've achieved something similar. That is where some operation or process requires administrative privileges and you're trying to do this via ASP.NET is to build a WCF service application (ideally as a self hosted service) and have it running as Administrator.

Then from your ASP.NET application you call methods in your service and it works.

**EDIT**

Here is the code to make a console application a WCF self hosted application

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var webServiceHhost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(AppCmdService), new Uri("http://localhost:7654"));
      ServiceEndpoint ep = webServiceHhost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(AppCmdService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
      var serviceDebugBehavior = webServiceHhost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
      serviceDebugBehavior.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
      webServiceHhost.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
      Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit ");
      Console.ReadLine();
      webServiceHhost.Close(); 
    }
  }
```

The class `AppCmdService` in the code listing above is my WCF service class

Comment: That's a very good idea, I'll definately go with that. But is CACLS my only option for creating accounts and setting the permissions?

Comment: @Jakob, I can't help you there, I'm afraid. I've used this technique many a times. Most recently to perform some actions using appcmd which is the command line tool to configure IIS, but it requires administrative privileges. Doing it this way worked like a charm. I've edited my answer to include some sample code for self hosted WCF service